# Alternative for yas/choose-value in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there an alternative for calling

```
$$(yas/choose-value '("public" "protected" "private"))
```

where I could cycle the choices with the tab key? The yasnippet one requires arrow keys to pick, which I obviously don't want to use.

Best regards

Comment: you can use C-n and  C-p for cycling through the choices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `ido-prompt`?

```
(setq yas/prompt-functions '(yas/ido-prompt
                             yas/completing-prompt))
```

There are many prompts defined for `yas/prompt-functions`.
Maybe you will prefer the other type of prompt.
See the [source code](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/blob/c28513cdf5dcad69e9b51911a9ae842cbd8168f3/yasnippet.el#L187) to find them.

I guess you will need the developmental version of yasnippet.